# How can I get the Latency of a process with Node.js on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm trying to get latency information from Windows with Node.js.

The values I want are in the Latency column under TCP Connections on the Network tab of the Windows Resource Monitor.

[image: Resource Monitor Screenshot]

I found one package called **systeminformation** but I cant retrieve process latency with it.

I would like to know a way to do it from Node.js.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by network latency?  Can you share a screenshot?  I don't see what you're talking about in the Resource Monitor.

Comment: @Brad sure. I have updated the question